# Group elements using 2 columns and then create a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

[image]

The table contains information about products bought by clients and their respective quantities.

I want to create a matrix of Client(rows) x Product(columns) and fill it with the quantities and input zeros when a client did not buy a product, like the following:

[image]

How can I do that?

Thanks,

Rodrigo.

Comment: add code to create your first dataframe if you want help ... of coarse someone might help even without it if your lucky

Answer (score 2):

```
df.set_index(['user','products']).unstack()
```

Comment: That was my last vote of the day.  I won't be able to vote for 4 more minutes.  I hope you appreciate that :-)

Comment: I appreciate buddy, I appreciate :D